# Searching 'select by color' for raster or map data

Tags: raster, digitizing, online

I'm planing to create an online map component with which the user can create/draw polygons based on underlying raster data.

Is there some library / tool / procedure existing which enables the creation of polygons based on the colors of the raster data (or map data) - something like the 'select by color' in photoshop?
Example: the user clicks in the center of a lake and the tool creates a polygon which covers the complete lake at the coastline.